# Does the US give full, unfettered access to the NCIC database to anyone other than Canada?

Tags: united-states, law, immigration, international

I know that the US shares full, real time access to the US NCIC database with Canada, but does it give this type of access to any other countries?

Many people seem to think that any immigration department of a country which is an Interpol member has full access to the US NCIC database for the purpose of screening people as they enter. Others believe that departments such as these only have partial access to the US NCIC. Still others believe that the US shares no such access with any country except Canada and that foreign governments must rely only on what information is supplied to Interpol in the form of Interpol notices or on their own local databases.

(Asking here because Law SE said it's off topic for them)

Comment: [Cross post](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/26470/100) on [Law.SE].

Comment: @Brythan Because they said it's not applicable there and to post here.

Comment: I think it's a fine question, but if you want to improve it, which people? Reference the claims and include quotes. Also, summarize NCIC database. What's in it? Source? Quote?

Comment: @TravelMate: The way you fix that is by deleting your question on Law.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Deleted from law. I didn't know I was supposed to do that. I'm very new to Stack Excange.

Answer (score 2):

Q: *Does the US give full, unfettered access to the NCIC database to anyone other than Canada?*

No. Federal Bureau of Investigation, [Privacy Impact Assessment for the National Crime Information Center](https://www.fbi.gov/file-repository/pia-ncic-020723.pdf), November 7, 2022 (PDF download.)

If the recipient of shared information is a foreign government, access is given on a case-by-case basis.

> **Section 4: Information Sharing**
> [...]
> Only Canada has direct access to the NCIC System. Other foreign governments may receive extracted information from the NCIC on a case-by-case basis. The exchange of NCIC information with foreign governments other than Canada is routed through DOJ’s USNCB INTERPOL.

Concerning foreign fugitives,

> **Foreign Fugitive File**
>
> The Foreign Fugitive File contains records from the International Criminal Police Organization (INTERPOL) and the Royal Canadian Mounted Police (RCMP). INTERPOL records within the Foreign Fugitive File contain information on persons wanted in other countries for crimes that would be felonies if committed in the United States. The wanting country must have signed an extradition treaty or convention with the United States, or the subject must be wanted for a violent crime or otherwise must be known to be violent, armed, or dangerous. The RCMP records within the Foreign Fugitive File contain information on persons who are wanted for violations of the Criminal Code of Canada and for whom there is an outstanding Canada-wide warrant. **Only the staff of INTERPOL’s United States National Central Bureau (USNCB) and the RCMP can enter records into this File.** (Emboldening added.)

Comment: does Canada have the right to share info with foreign governments?

Comment: @whoisit - The [Canadian Police Information Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadian_Police_Information_Centre) (CPIC) is operated by the RCMP and interfaces with the US NCIC. Canada may share from the CPIC whatever it chooses, but the sharing and use of information from the NCIC are subject to terms of access granted to Canada's CPIC. *See also*, [Policy for Use of Information from Canada](https://wiki.nlets.org/index.php/Section_32:_Communicating_with_Canada#Policy_for_Use_of_Information_from_Canada).